# Different DigestValue for the same XML document

Tags: c#, xml-dsig

I have signed xml document [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxmD9cBSx_KHMm9WWGdVaFdzb3c/edit?usp=sharing)

The digest value of the document is *atHP855e32qDMu4fzAZr+wXRqfeLh9HTpnAlAFy/jDg=*
When I try to check it with code below the result is *Ppk6zE8XY4zaIPco/fY/sSKog3imkmko8CMAIHVNwTw=* 
I think the problem is in Body tag that contain whitespaces. If sign this document without whitespaces, digest values are equal.

Who can spot a mistake?

```
public static byte[] GetDigest(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        var nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(
          "Signature", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

        var signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        var signatureDescription = CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod) as SignatureDescription;
        var hashAlgorithm = signatureDescription.CreateDigest();

        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument
        {
            PreserveWhitespace = true
        };

        var body = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ReportEnvelope/Body");

        XmlNodeList transformNode = ((XmlElement)(nodeList[0])).GetElementsByTagName("Transform");

        xmlDocument.AppendChild(xmlDocument.ImportNode(body, true));

        var transform = signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethodObject;
        transform.LoadInnerXml(transformNode);
        transform.LoadInput(xmlDocument);
        return transform.GetDigestedOutput(hashAlgorithm);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue as well and it has something to do with how SignedXml creates the hash digest. In .NET 4, it completely ignores any whitespace in the the XML.

[SignedXml.CheckSignature fails in .NET 4 but it works in .NET 3.5, 3 or 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632630/signedxml-checksignature-fails-in-net-4-but-it-works-in-net-3-5-3-or-2)